# Redirecting/Ignoring S3 index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to utilize the main subfolder on S3 without the need to append the /index.html after the URL of that bucket?

For example my bucket URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/hello/, however this shows a Access Denied error, and I need to enter /index.html to view it.

Is it possible to somehow remove the need for index.html and/or redirect it, so that my main URL will be the subfolder? EG: if I access https://s3.amazonaws.com/hello/ it works, and shows the index.html file (but without the filename, as would happen on a 'regular' Linux type server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a default page, but only if you configure the bucket for **Static Website Sharing**, which also results in a slightly different URL format.

[image: Static Website Sharing on Amazon S3]

The URL would look like:

```
<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/hello
```

See: [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Comment: Thanks. So it doesnt seem to be possible to do what I plan under the s3.amazonaws.com subdomain. Does this only apply to index.html Index documents, though? EG: Can I achieve what I want if I use anothername.html ?

Comment: Using Static Website Sharing you can define a default document (eg `index.html`) and a 403 document (eg `error.html`). You can specify exactly which files to use (as per the picture above). Without static website sharing, you must provide the **full path** to the object.